# Creating multiple instances of my exe application when using launch4j

Tags: java, launch4j

My application is running correctly. The only issue is when I go to open a second window.

- I am **unable** to open multiple instances of my application when I convert it to an **exe**.
- I am **able** to open multiple instances of it when it is a **jar**.

When I go to open a second instance (by clicking on the exe) nothing happens. How can I fix this?

I am using Launch4J to convert my jar to an exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution. It was simple in the end. 
Looking up the manual did the trick. http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html

I opened the launch4j xml config file and removed the following lines

```
<singleInstance>
    <mutexName>text</mutexName>
   <windowTitle>text</windowTitle>
</singleInstance>
```

Then opened that file again in launch4j and built the wrapper.